# Graph databases (eg Neo4j) for similar matches

Tags: algorithm, neo4j

I am investigating an algorithm for similar matches and am trying to work out if a graph database would be the best data model for my solution. Let's use "find a similar car" as an example.

If we had car data like:

```
Owner   |  Make    |  Model    |  Engine   |  Colour

Jeff    |  Ford    |  Focus    |  1400cc   |  Light Red
Bob     |  Ford    |  Focus    |  1800cc   |  Dark Red
Paul    |  Ford    |  Mondeo   |  2000cc   |  Blue
```

My understanding is that a graph database would be extremely performant with queries like:

```
Get me all owners who own a car of the same make as Jeff
```

Because you would start at the 'Jeff' node, follow the 'Make' edge to the 'Ford' node, and from here follow all the 'Owner' edges to get all people that own a Ford.

Now my question is would it be performant to do "Similar" lookups, eg:

```
Get me all owners whose car is within 500cc of Jeff
```

Presumably if you had "1400cc" as an Engine node, you would not be able to traverse the graph from here to find other Engines of a similar size, and so it would not be performant. My thinking is you would have to run some sort of overnight batch to create new edges between all Engine nodes, with the size difference between those two engines.

Have I understood correctly? Does a graph database seem like a good fit, or is there some other storage / retrieval / analysis method that would fit exactly to this problem?

What about in the case where I want to see the top 10 most similar cars, and my algorithm for similarity is something like "Start at 100%, deduct 2% for every 100cc difference, deduct 20% for different model, deduct 30% for different make, deduct 20% for different colour (or 5% if it's different shades of the same colour)". The only way I can think of doing this currently so that an application would be performant, would be to have a background task constantly iterating through the entire dataset and creating "similarity score" edges between every Owner.

Obviously with small datasets the solution doesn't really matter as any hodge-podge will be performant, but eventually we will have potentially hundreds of thousands of cars.

Any thoughts appreciated!

Comment: It's a great question, but I'm not sure if that's really a suitable one for StackOverflow. This problem can be modeled in a graph in different ways. But I'm not sure that there's going to be a *best* answer for this problem.

Comment: @manonthemat yeah I wasn't sure if this was a good place, but I wasn't sure where else to ask. I'm hoping a kindly master of Neo4j will take pity on me and either say "yes, we had a similar problem and this is how we did it" or "no, you should look into X instead"

Answer (score 1):

To get you started, here is a simple model, illustrated using sample data for "Jeff":

```
(make:Make {name: "Ford"})-[:MAKES]->(model:Model {name: "Focus", cc: 14000, year: 2016})
(o:Owner {name: "Jeff"})-[:OWNS]->(v:Vehicle {vin: "WVWZZZ6XZXW068123", plate: "ABC123", color: "Light Red"})-[:MODEL]->(model)
```

To get `all owners who own a car of the same make as Jeff`:

```
MATCH (o1:Owner { name: "Jeff" })-[:OWNS]->(:Vehicle)-[:MODEL]->(model:Model)<-[:MAKES]-(make:Make)
MATCH (make)-[:MAKES]->(:Model)<-[:MODEL]-(:Vehicle)<-[:OWNS]-(owners:Owner)
RETURN DISTINCT owners;
```

To get `all owners whose car is within 500cc of Jeff`:

```
MATCH (o1:Owner { name: "Jeff" })-[:OWNS]->(:Vehicle)-[:MODEL]->(model:Model)<-[:MAKES]-(make:Make)
MATCH (make)-[:MAKES]->(x:Model)
WHERE (x.cc >= model.cc - 500) AND (x.cc <= model.cc + 500)
MATCH (x)<-[:MODEL]-(:Vehicle)<-[:OWNS]-(owners:Owner)
RETURN DISTINCT owners;
```

The above queries will be a bit faster if you first create an index on `:Owner(name)`:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Owner(name);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Am I right in thinking that using "WHERE" is not as performant as using "MATCH"? Or have I misunderstood? Would this query scale to millions of vehicles?

Comment: In practice, we will end up having about 15 different criteria, eg "engine within 500cc, distance within 15 miles, price within £1000, etc etc"

Comment: A `MATCH` cannot specify a range test. But there would be no difference in general anway.

Answer (score 0):

As @manonthemat said in the comments, there's no best answer for your question, but I'll try to provide you a datamodel to help you :

First of all, you have to know which properties will be "the same" on your matches, like this :

> Get me all owners who own a car of the same make as Jeff

Here, you'll want to create one Node per Make, and create a relationship from each car to show their brand.

Example data model for this use case:

[image: Data model example]

You can still create one node per property value, but it's not always the best since if you have an infinite property value possibilities, you'll have to create one node per value.

Keep in mind that Graph Databases are really good for data modeling, because their relationship management is really easy to understand and use. So everything is about data model, and each data model is unique. [This guide](http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-data-modeling/) should help you.

Comment: Thanks Supamiu. I guess what I'm struggling with is I can see how to get things that are the "same" (eg several cars link to the same Make) but not how to get things that are "similar" based on some definition of similarity. In MySQL I would put my "similarity" rules in a separate table and use a number of inner joins to generate scores between objects, but I have no idea if this is possible, practical or performant in a graph

Comment: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-refcard/ This should help you a lot with neo4j query language A.K.A Cypher